# Flask end response and continue processing

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way in Flask to send the response to the client and then continue doing some processing? I have a few book-keeping tasks which are to be done, but I don't want to keep the client waiting.

Note that these are actually really fast things I wish to do, thus creating a new thread, or using a queue, isn't really appropriate here. (One of these fast things is actually adding something to a job queue.)

Comment: Look at `celery` or another questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/16870858/880326 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15969213/880326.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sadly teardown callbacks do not execute after the response has been returned to the client:

```
import flask
import time
app = flask.Flask("after_response")

@app.teardown_request
def teardown(request):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("teardown_request")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Success!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When curling this you'll note a 2s delay before the response displays, rather than the curl ending immediately and then a log 2s later. This is further confirmed by the logs:

```
teardown_request
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2018 15:41:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The correct way to execute after a response is returned is to use WSGI middleware that adds a hook to the [close method of the response iterator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#specification-details). This is not quite as simple as the `teardown_request` decorator, but it's still pretty straight-forward:

```
import traceback
from werkzeug.wsgi import ClosingIterator

class AfterResponse:
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.callbacks = []
        if app:
            self.init_app(app)

    def __call__(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
        return callback

    def init_app(self, app):
        # install extension
        app.after_response = self

        # install middleware
        app.wsgi_app = AfterResponseMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, self)

    def flush(self):
        for fn in self.callbacks:
            try:
                fn()
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()

class AfterResponseMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application, after_response_ext):
        self.application = application
        self.after_response_ext = after_response_ext

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        iterator = self.application(environ, start_response)
        try:
            return ClosingIterator(iterator, [self.after_response_ext.flush])
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return iterator
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
@app.after_response
def after():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("after_response")
```

From the shell you will see the response return immediately and then 2 seconds later the `after_response` will hit the logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2018 15:41:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
after_response
```

This is a summary of a previous answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response/51013358#51013358).

Comment: This answer is confusing without the `AfterResponse(app)` line from the linked answer.

Answer (score 16):

***QUICK*** and ***EASY*** method.

We will use pythons ***Thread*** Library to acheive this.

Your API consumer has sent something to process and which is processed by ***my_task()*** function which takes ***10 seconds*** to execute.
But the consumer of the API wants a response as soon as they hit your API which is ***return_status()*** function.

You ***tie*** the ***my_task*** to a ***thread*** and then return the quick response to the API consumer, while in the background the big process gets compelete.

Below is a simple POC.

```
import os
from flask import Flask,jsonify
import time
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

@app.route('/add_')
def return_status():
    """Return first the response and tie the my_task to a thread"""
    Thread(target = my_task).start()
    return jsonify('Response asynchronosly')

def my_task():
    """Big function doing some job here I just put pandas dataframe to csv conversion"""
    time.sleep(10)
    import pandas as pd
    pd.DataFrame(['sameple data']).to_csv('./success.csv')
    return print('large function completed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this would not work if you're using the processes option in flask to serve parallel requests. The process would  exit as soon as you return the response, killing the thread started to perform the task.

Comment: `return print('large function completed')` makes no sense, `print()` always returns `None`. Furthermore, you're not doing anything with the return value of `my_task()`

Comment: Right. Thread didnt work for me

Comment: If this doesn't work, why the hell has 14 upvotes ?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with my blog. I wanted to send notification emails to those subscribed to comments when a new comment was posted, but I did not want to have the person posting the comment waiting for all the emails to be sent before he gets his response.

I used a `multiprocessing.Pool` for this. I started a pool of one worker (that was enough, low traffic site) and then each time I need to send an email I prepare everything in the Flask view function, but pass the final `send_email` call to the pool via `apply_async`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example on how to use celery from within Flask
here https://gist.github.com/jzempel/3201722

The gist of the idea (pun intended) is to define the long, book-keeping tasks as @celery.task and use apply_async[1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics) or delay to from within the view to start the task

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Teardown Callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/#teardown-callbacks) would support what you want. And you might want to combine it with the pattern from [Per-Request After-Request Callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/) to help with organizing the code.

Comment: This looks closest to what I want. It's not path specific but that pattern shows how it can be easily done.

Comment: Just an update-- this does *not* accomplish what the asker wants because Flask still waits on the teardown functions to finish before releasing the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with WSGI's `close` protocol, exposed from the Werkzeug Response object's `call_on_close` decorator. Explained in this other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080968/78903